# How to create a select list of which the selected item is used as parameter in VBO rules component?

Tags: rules, views

It's a common scenario, but I couldn't find a solution yet:

I have a view (a list of tasks) with checkboxes (views bulk operations)

I want:
1) a dropdown select list of taxonomy terms 'Priority' above the view.
2) a rules component that uses the selected taxonomy term, as parameter for applying the priority to the selected tasks.

Answer (score 0):

VBO uses the core 'actions'. You can create new actions with [hook_action_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_action_info/7).

The https://www.drupal.org/project/examples module has a good action example.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I don't want to use custom coding if possible.

Comment: I see the examples list, but which one do you refer to? Can you copy past that here please? It appears that without coding this issue may not be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this without creating a custom module if you were willing to choose the taxonomy on a second screen.

The Rules module allows you to create custom Actions in `admin/config/workflow/rules/components`.

Click 'create new component', give it a useful, descriptive name and continue.  Under actions click 'new action' and choose 'set a data value'.  Choose the relevant field, and click save and continue until you are back at the main components screen.

You can now use your new component with VBO in your view.

Comment: Yes I know that method of submitting the taxonomy on a second screen, and that is not what I'm looking for. Besides that, out of the box Rules does not provide for a select list, the users would have to submit the taxonomy term id's which is not the way to go.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to make a custom form then, you might be able to embed the view in it... or maybe you can use Page Manager to piece it together.

Comment: I like the idea of using Page Manager, do you have an idea how to get a parameter select list going?

Comment: There's an excellent tutorial on Page Manager [here](https://drupalize.me/videos/overview-page-manager-series?p=1147), but if you're still against having the parameter chosen after the action you will almost certainly need a custom form.